# iOS Simulator run in 568x320

Tags: ios, simulator, widescreen

Is it possible to run the iOS simulator iphone as 568x320? Or disable the retina frame buffer? The reason I ask is I'm trying to do a screen capture on the iOS Simulator for a game trailer and running it with the retina display causes huge drops in performance.

The non retina iPhone simulation running at 480x320 runs great but I would really like to demonstrate the game running on the taller display.

I have attempted to create a new simulator hardware profile in the simulator app by creating a copy of iPhone (Retina 4-inch).device info and modifying the resolution in the info.plist to 568x320 but the profile becomes hidden from the simulator when I do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There are no iOS devices with a 568x320 display. The iPhone 5 with that aspect ratio is double that, 1136x640.

Answer (score 0):

When your simulator is running:

1. Select "Device" - "iPhone (Retina 4-Inch)" from the simulator's "Hardware" menu.
2. Select "Scale" - "50%" from the "Window" menu. (Or press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.)

Clearly, this is going to be the retina rendition (which is 1136 x 640), but scaled down to look like 568 x 320.

Comment: Thank you for your reply rob. You are correct I can do that but because it is still running the retina display frame buffers i still experience lower performance than if the simulator was running non-retina.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it was not possible to do what I initially intended to do.

But through use of AirPlay and AirServer I was able to mirror my app running on the iPhone 5 to my mac. I was then able to screen cap the AirPlayed footage with full performance of running natively on the device.